# Updating variable from localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

While refreshing the page the value of TotalPrice is true until click the button, the value of TotalPrice starts from 0. So now how can I add the new price to `TotalPrice`?

```
/********************************************************************/
var price=0;
var TotalPrice=localStorage.getItem("x");
         $("#total").html(TotalPrice);
$(".addToCard").on("click",function(){
            if($(this).text()=='add to cart')
            {$(this).html("remove from cart");
                var clickedButtonIndex=( $('button').index(this) );
                clickedButtonIndex=clickedButtonIndex-2;
                price +=resp2[clickedButtonIndex].price;
                /************adding to local storage**************/
                $("#total").html(price);
                localStorage.setItem("x",price);
```

Comment: Is there any question ?

Comment: The question is very unclear, also you've left a lot of code that makes it harder to understand what the question is.
Please leave just what you're having trouble with and fix your question and we'll try to help